# Background video stuck in a fixed position and not moving with the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

While scrolling my background video is stuck on the screen. I have set the position to fixed but I want it to stop acting when the next container starts.

I also want the text of that video container to go sliding up through the video while scrolling and the same with the next container texts

I have tried replacing the `position: fixed` with `background-poistion: fixed` with no desirable changes

```css
#title {
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(243, 30, 112);
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo {
  width: 4%;
  top: 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.top-container {
  padding: 60px 30px 30px 30px;
  margin: -80px -8px -40px -30px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, blue, white, yellow);
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  ;
}

#header-img {
  width: 3%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20%;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -48px -6px 0px -10px;
  padding: 9px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#cover {
  margin: 0.5px -10px 0px -10px;
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -98px;
  height: 550px;
  object-fit: cover;
  align-self: center;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.01em 16px;
  padding-top: 0.01em;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0.01em;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  justify-items: center;
}

#sml {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.policies {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}

#prod {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 860px;
}


/* .centered{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(228, 56, 56);
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
    <title>Giovanni's Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inknut+Antiqua:wght@300&display=swap" type='text/css'>
  </head>



  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <header id="header">
    <img id="header-img" src="logo2.svg" alt="a logo">

    <nav id="nav-bar">

      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <video autoplay muted loop id="cover">
        <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2021-05/small_watermarked/210512_01_Music_4k_009_preview.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <p id="sml">Since 1961</p>
    <div id="text">
      <h4>Guitars and Basses.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="policies">
    <h5 id="prod">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vitae, minima. Dolore quod quam similique, odio facere necessitatibus quas officia libero non eveniet sit ipsum consectetur sunt distinctio omnis dolor, doloremque quaerat, labore quia fugiat
      porro facilis inventore! Nulla magnam labore assumenda laboriosam incidunt nisi dignissimos maxime repudiandae, maiores ipsa quod eligendi, at nesciunt quos. Commodi vitae blanditiis ratione assumenda. Voluptatem placeat provident illum officia
      fugit sequi vero nisi quam. Ipsum rerum eius ratione ea asperiores possimus praesentium commodi fuga, minima eum laudantium suscipit nostrum eveniet perferendis deserunt laboriosam blanditiis neque, alias, voluptatem eligendi dolorum vitae quae!
      Aut amet aliquid libero pariatur, blanditiis harum atque. Necessitatibus, iure? Odio quae magnam aliquid incidunt officia error perspiciatis illum voluptatum hic? Quas alias nemo accusantium temporibus error? Provident fuga fugiat eius enim totam
      soluta saepe beatae accusantium asperiores sunt nesciunt ipsa, eaque dolorum et perspiciatis dignissimos sequi? Adipisci dolorem doloremque facere pariatur inventore fuga cupiditate vel quidem enim a quia, ab odio, eveniet dignissimos dolores aliquid
      tenetur autem, quis nam quibusdam. Vel, quam excepturi. Fugit maxime voluptatum nam maiores delectus, quo illo consequatur aliquid dolorem excepturi quia sit laudantium quam deserunt numquam adipisci voluptatem eveniet voluptates, sed veniam rem
      reprehenderit corporis? Blanditiis quod, aut consequuntur commodi nisi, cupiditate dolor nihil aperiam deserunt quaerat molestiae quis nesciunt, laborum unde incidunt culpa! Possimus commodi impedit ullam eius aut veritatis expedita voluptatum nam
      deserunt ipsa, eum consequatur iusto doloribus enim voluptas labore ut nobis obcaecati illo perspiciatis quam similique provident. Culpa, quos sint eveniet eaque sequi doloremque mollitia nesciunt alias maiores debitis natus soluta. Explicabo dolorum
      ipsum dolores quaerat doloribus ad commodi nulla cupiditate doloremque. Quas iusto velit pariatur voluptatibus labore? Assumenda, cumque! Dicta molestias, harum officiis aperiam velit temporibus optio obcaecati nemo sint quam debitis nostrum. Esse,
      dolor. Excepturi provident ea ab, quas fugiat, dolores magni sapiente ipsum, accusantium commodi ex itaque enim! Beatae odio ipsa quisquam enim eius expedita obcaecati doloribus libero illum minima dolor asperiores accusantium, saepe suscipit facilis
      consequatur laboriosam, optio nemo cupiditate commodi necessitatibus aperiam. Enim perferendis ullam cum beatae soluta quas aspernatur labore itaque veniam delectus dolor debitis, voluptatibus veritatis deserunt nihil blanditiis velit ex obcaecati
      necessitatibus officiis minima omnis odit. Explicabo est consequuntur, ea nemo asperiores placeat nisi cum fugiat reiciendis repudiandae unde ipsum, distinctio nesciunt eos eligendi. Quo provident atque aperiam nemo numquam quaerat aliquid! Quibusdam
      culpa obcaecati quaerat excepturi veniam! Ut aliquam dolorum vitae praesentium reprehenderit? Unde hic consequatur officia, amet doloremque expedita! Voluptas accusamus animi ipsum quisquam atque et, ducimus est sequi quos quibusdam, nulla omnis,
      magnam debitis molestiae sit eius soluta impedit iusto esse voluptatem minus fugiat dolor provident? Adipisci ipsam eos, id ad accusamus voluptates accusantium maiores quas quos nobis, optio culpa assumenda similique voluptatum rem dolorum veniam
      doloremque ducimus quasi sit. Quos blanditiis natus in nisi sint illo unde inventore repudiandae, beatae eius ut vero ex at veritatis dolor itaque obcaecati adipisci. Itaque beatae omnis tempora et eos debitis, amet incidunt consequuntur aut aliquid,
      porro distinctio expedita repellat tempore. Similique iste dolores excepturi esse laborum ad, asperiores voluptate. Cum harum aliquid alias qui perferendis magnam maiores eligendi expedita et sapiente quibusdam animi unde minus, mollitia nihil repellat
      delectus cupiditate, architecto eveniet! Modi iusto vero molestiae laudantium, corporis optio a vel perspiciatis quisquam alias maiores ratione, ea ipsam id quam dolorem quis consequuntur. Excepturi at explicabo doloremque asperiores cupiditate?
      Cum sunt dolorem similique eveniet eligendi, obcaecati nesciunt vel perspiciatis delectus magnam, illum doloribus aut amet ipsam veritatis laboriosam quidem alias illo saepe rerum! Et dicta quo tempore eos dolore? Iste hic recusandae, blanditiis
      cumque veniam quas architecto. Repudiandae aliquam necessitatibus magni rerum quisquam eum atque dolorum placeat dignissimos. A qui cumque voluptates sint optio voluptatibus vitae harum tenetur reiciendis id eos quidem tempore laborum in error obcaecati
      odit ex et ratione, eaque assumenda aut eius! Impedit, quis. Nulla inventore neque omnis qui eveniet molestias eius sint vel voluptas! Tempora, animi? Sequi veniam iure quibusdam repellat, dolorum, id earum accusamus reiciendis at possimus adipisci
      a similique?</h5>
  </section>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: looking good; you need to: [1] add `margin: 0` to the body;  [2]remove all margins on #cover and use `position: relative`;   i see you have z-index: -1 on the video but that needs to be on the container of the video;  then you will have to fiddle w #prod to get it just right

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this? If you want this, simply delete the html in the video section and use the code snippet.

```js
var video = document.querySelector('#ds');
window.onscroll = () => {
  if (document.querySelector('.hd-a').getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 0) {
    video.pause();
  } else {
    if (!video.play()) {
      video.play();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hd-a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hd-a #ds {
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}

.hd-a .desc {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.desc p {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hd-a">
  <div class="desc">
    <h1>Lorquasi, velit, quam sit ipsa officia illo veritatis expedita</h1>
    <p>Loremque adipisci sequi animi dicta!</p>
  </div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="ds">
                <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2021-05/small_watermarked/210512_01_Music_4k_009_preview.webm" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem amet officia mollitia repudiandae autem, voluptates cupiditate consequuntur aspernatur repellat atque eum error dolorum quos numquam natus! Officia laborum facere earum iste molestias dignissimos
  laboriosam, aliquam vel incidunt fuga. Dolorem doloribus veritatis magni expedita voluptas sit earum laudantium blanditiis reprehenderit quis! Impedit excepturi consequuntur porro tempore atque sequi eaque unde ut neque rerum odio nisi repellendus veniam
  voluptates veritatis doloribus cumque consequatur sunt beatae aperiam quasi, non sapiente! Praesentium, eaque aut! Amet illo nostrum non qui blanditiis repellat fugiat, voluptatum reiciendis, asperiores totam harum aliquid facere consectetur, corporis
  laboriosam porro impedit delectus quas natus! Sequi deserunt aliquid veritatis ea doloribus quasi neque molestias atque, itaque dicta corrupti, necessitatibus a quaerat, quia explicabo quisquam iste est aut deleniti id. Sed blanditiis nemo eos debitis
  perferendis suscipit hic nesciunt, illo ducimus praesentium laborum quaerat eum. Voluptate, cum obcaecati? Voluptatem perferendis in animi sit repellat! At dolor eveniet dolores iure est sunt dolorem magnam illum ea, numquam sapiente atque eius voluptates
  veniam, nihil expedita laborum quis ipsam labore officiis animi. Exercitationem, qui possimus nesciunt maxime id voluptates maiores, error unde modi debitis similique nihil temporibus! Quae eius iure minus ut eaque architecto quaerat similique incidunt
  modi illum, expedita natus tenetur. Similique possimus quam vero quia sit doloremque tempore. Beatae ipsa similique voluptatibus maiores perspiciatis excepturi voluptates? Doloribus impedit dolor debitis quibusdam qui quidem! Incidunt itaque, vitae
  laboriosam, optio impedit aliquid at cumque fugiat consequuntur praesentium vel excepturi nihil omnis animi voluptatum officiis voluptatem vero aspernatur aliquam? Omnis itaque ratione ducimus inventore debitis, pariatur, similique iste cumque nobis
  exercitationem rem consequatur possimus veniam soluta, praesentium ut repellat illum. Nemo odio, quaerat numquam, expedita obcaecati saepe culpa esse amet provident ratione unde officiis. Quod aperiam molestiae ex quaerat animi iusto autem tempora,
  neque consectetur nostrum assumenda mollitia natus tempore, dolorum soluta asperiores vel ipsam facilis non aliquam! Doloribus, adipisci at praesentium accusantium laborum aut dicta cum atque dolore qui quis magnam fuga delectus cumque error enim esse
  eum? Nulla doloribus quis voluptas repellat molestias cupiditate est quibusdam. Expedita tempore corporis non iure animi, amet esse quaerat error impedit aliquam ipsum, et odio, accusamus earum ratione ut. Omnis ipsam iure error ullam ducimus sunt consequatur
  neque itaque culpa aliquid hic quo, ratione nulla a amet earum quae iste minus fuga reiciendis nam dolore debitis molestiae. Qui, sapiente. Et illo vel voluptas nioluptas hic eum modi, sint temporibus officia assumenda est corrupti sed quisquam minus
  ab inventore eveniet eos sequi consequatur. Labore, delectus doloribus iure id odit nemo accusantium fugit exercitationem odio nobis consequatur error placeat assumenda pariatur adipisci libero nesciunt voluptas laborum ratione minima. Eius, facere,
  recusandae pore voluptatem quaerat fugit cumque quam ex eaque, dolores, repellendus earum officia sapiente magnam aliquam optio! Alias quia autem debitis consequuntur temporibus ipsam quam placeat eum iste atque ea quod nobis labore non impedit voluptas
  dolor recusandae eaque nam omnis fugit, at, delectus quae? Porro error aut rem at earum, officiis placeat magnam magni eius. Quasi eveniet ex quaerat dolorem impedit corporis aspernatur, non consequuntur.</p>
```